# .htaccess 301 redirect with regex

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, regex

I am trying to fix a lot of errors in our old website regarding a thing with product pages having multiple URLs associated with a single product.

I am hoping that I can use regular expressions in with a regular redirect 301 line but so far I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is what I am trying:

```
redirect 301 /products/(.*?)/(.*?)/5702/(.*?).html http://mycompany.com/footwear/wolverine-boots-waterproof-durashocks-work-boots-2582-33390.html
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just for clarification, we are talking about Apache, right?

Comment: Yes I am using Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *redirect* directive doesn't take regular expressions. What you probably want to use instead is [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

Answer (score 1):

you could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

with something like:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^/products/(.?)/(.?)/5702/(.*).html http://mycompany.com/footwear/wolverine-boots-waterproof-durashocks-work-boots-2582-33390.html [L,R=301]
```

can you give example of structure you are trying to redirect?
es: /product/aa/bb/1234/aaaaaaaaaaa.html

Comment: the first regex block is in the format 23_45_67 (numbers with _ between them) and the second one is a regular int and the third block is a string.